# Remove or pop is not eliminating all the elements

Tags: python, list

```
lis = [3,4,5,6]
for j in lis:
    lis.remove(j)
print(lis)
```

Output:

```
[3,4]
```

I tried `pop()` also but couldn't remove all elements

Comment: after removing one element size of the list also remove so for loop not removing all elimentt

Comment: **Don't mutate the list while iterating through it**. And rthe result would be `[4, 6]` in Cpython3.8. After you remove 1st element, now `4` is 1st element but iteration index is at 2nd, it removes `5` which at 2nd index, now `6` comes to 2nd index, iteration index become 3 and stops.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why you are not able to remove all the elements is that when you are removing an element from the array the `j` value skips to the next value's next value instead of the next. So only the alternative values will be removed by this method.

```py
lis = [3,4,5,6]
for j in lis:
    lis.remove(j)
    print(j)
print(lis)
```

Output

```
3
5
[4,6]
```

As you can see in this output `print(j)` does not print all the elements, it only prints `3` and `5`. So only `3` and `5` are removed.

**How to solve it?**

So you can either use `clear()`, like this

```
lis.clear()
```

Or if you want to use iteration you can do it with `pop()` like this

```
for i in range(len(lis)):
   lis.pop(i)
```

Or you can create a shallow copy of the list and `remove()` the elements one by one like this

```
for i in list(lis):
   lis.remove(i)
```

Or you can use `:` to return the whole slice of the array (copy of the array)

```
for i in x[:]:
   x.remove(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

use clear to clear all the element of the list

```
lis =[3,4,5,6]
lis.clear()
print(lis)
```

Output:

```
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

A correct solution will be to create a shallow copy with the help of `list()` function.

```
lis =[3,4,5,6]
for j in list(lis):
    lis.remove(j)
print(lis)
```

Output

```
[]
```